# javascript match() without slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this code:

```
var k= 'test';

var m = document.cookie.match(k+'=([^;]*)');
```

and I'm trying to get which cookies will be read.
Normally there is a leading slash in the regex like: `x.match (/\d+/g);` but not
here, so my question is how has the cookie to look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If regexp is a non-RegExp object, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(regexp).

Comment: do you have any example how the cookie look like?

Comment: @hamburger it would match that regex. So `test=` followed by any amount of non-`;` characters.

Comment: thats means the regex ist between the brackest [^;]*
and the cookiename must contain an equal signe?

Comment: @hamburger — No. The whole string will be converted to a regular expression.

Comment: so the cookiename has to look like this: test=(hello)

Comment: Yes, that is *possible*. It will match the regex. `k+'=([^;]*)` simply produces `/test=([^;]*)/`